# Can't reproduce a 3d plot correctly in LaTeX

Tags: pgfplots

This is my first post here,
I was trying to plot the function: 10*cos(2*sqrt(x^2+y^2)-6)
with axis configuration: *x=-5..5 y=-5..5 z=-50...50*

So I wrote down this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        colormap/cool,
        xmin=-5, xmax=5,
        ymin=-5, ymax=5,
        zmin=-50, zmax=50
        ]
        \addplot3[surf]
        {10*cos(2*sqrt(x^2+y^2)-6)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Turns out this is the result i get:

[image: plot]

But the actual result should look like this one, from google plots:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to fix my code so that it would look like the one from google?
I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what it is...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The problem is that pgfplots takes, by default, the arguments of trigonometric functions to be in degrees. You can change this by adding `trig format=rad`. I also changed the view.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[trig format=rad,view={35}{42},
        colormap/cool,
        xmin=-5, xmax=5,
        ymin=-5, ymax=5,
        zmin=-50, zmax=50
        ]
        \addplot3[surf]
        {10*cos(2*sqrt(x^2+y^2)-6)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You saved my life